# How to replaceByImage() instead of drawImage() on html canvas (ignore opacity)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to draw an image (which can have transparent parts) on the canvas, totally replacing the canvas content by the sourve image (unlike in a `source-over` composition operation).

The resulting canvas would have the exact same values as the source image. I can't find any composition operation to perform this.

I can always clear the canvas before calling `drawImage()` but I was wondering if there is a faster/better way.

Comment: Use `context.clearRect` -- it's optimized to be the fastest way of clearing the canvas in preparation for new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the copy mode if you want to replace everything (as it seem from the text in the question):

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
```

If you only want to remove parts of the canvas, ie. area where you content will be drawn to, then clearRect can be used:

```
ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);   // replace with values
```

Comment: The `copy` mode completely removes the previous drawing when something new is drawn in; this is not what I want. I want to replace the previous drawing only where something new is added. Can you rephrase your answer (advice to use `clearRect` instead of `copy` mode) so that I accept it?

Comment: @arthur.sw answer reworded